# I added a class then didn't need it, now it won't build my project without it. How do I fix this?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm building a WPF project in Visual Studio and I added a class using the File>add class technique with VS.  I ended up realizing I didn't need this new class so I deleted the .cs file that it created.  However, now when I try to build the project, I get an error (failure to find source file x.cs).  What do I need to do so that the build doesn't expect to find the x.cs file when building?

Comment: is the file still in the project tree? did you just delete the file from the hard drive without deleting it form the project?

Comment: Remove reference to this file by using menu: `Project->Exclude From Project` ;)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I did just delete it from the HD like a fool.

Comment: @MaciejLos I'm not seeing that option under Project, but I'll find it, Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on situation there's few ways to achieve that:

> **Removing**
>
> To remove an item or project
>
> 1. In Solution Explorer, select the item you want to remove.
> 2. On the Edit menu, select Remove.
>
> **Deleting**
>
> To permanently delete an item
>
> 1. In Solution Explorer, select the item you want to delete.
> 2. On the Edit menu, select Delete.
>
> **Excluding**
>
> To temporarily exclude an item that represents a file
>
> 1. In Solution Explorer, select the item you want to exclude.
> 2. On the Project menu, select Exclude From Project.
>
> **Excluding Items from Deployment Projects**
>
> To exclude an item from a deployment project
>
> 1. In Solution Explorer, select the file you want to exclude.
> 2. On the Solution Explorer toolbar, select Properties.
>
> **Unloading**
>
> To temporarily unload a project from a solution
>
> 1. In Solution Explorer, select the project you want to unload.
> 2. On the Project menu, select Unload Project.

More at: [Visual Studio: How to: Remove, Delete, and Exclude Items (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebzhwsk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)